# SQL - Get row number of the nth distinct foreign key

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a stored procedure that has a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` inside of it. Now I need to return all the rows that have total number of distinct foreign keys to nth (let's say 10)!

For example lets say that my table looks like this:

```
    +----+---------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
    | FK | Name          | UserName       | Asignee      | Comment       |
    +----+---------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
    | 31 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Test Agent... |
    | 31 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Test Agent... |
    | 32 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | test          |
    | 32 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | test          |
    | 32 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | test          |
    | 33 | Test Agent... | Rachel Stalony | Gary Pannu   | test          |
    | 33 | Test Agent... | Rachel Stalony | Sunny Tiwana | test          |
    | 33 | Test Agent... | Rachel Stalony | Manny Virk   | test          |
    | 34 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | test          |
    | 34 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | test          |
    | 34 | Test Agent... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | test          |
    | 35 | Test TeamW... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | adsf asdf ... |
    | 35 | Test TeamW... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | adsf asdf ... |
    | 36 | New Agent ... | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Test comme... |
    | 36 | New Agent ... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | Test comme... |
    | 36 | New Agent ... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Test comme... |
    | 37 | Test TeamW... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | Some comme... |
    | 37 | Test TeamW... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Some comme... |
    | 38 | qwer qwer.... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | some new c... |
    | 38 | qwer qwer.... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | some new c... |
    | 42 | asdfsafdsa... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | NULL          |
    | 42 | asdfsafdsa... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | NULL          |
    | 43 | 20161214 J... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | My Test co... |
    | 43 | 20161214 J... | Manny Virk     | Sunny Tiwana | My Test co... |
    | 41 | Happy Wedd... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | Svi togeth... |
    | 41 | Happy Wedd... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Svi togeth... |
    | 44 | Call all l... | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Call all l... |
    | 44 | Call all l... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Call all l... |
    | 45 | Reperition... | Manny Virk     | Gary Pannu   | NULL          |
    | 45 | Reperition... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | NULL          |
    | 46 | Some Task     | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Some Task ... |
    | 46 | Some Task     | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Some Task ... |
    | 47 | asdf          | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | 6twdfwu       |
    | 47 | asdf          | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | 6twdfwu       |
    | 48 | Test Daily... | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Test Daily... |
    | 48 | Test Daily... | Manny Virk     | Manny Virk   | Test Daily... |
    | 49 | Test Weekl... | Manny Virk     | Sumit Sharda | Test Weekl....|
    +----+---------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want the procedure to return me all rows up to FK=43 including all FK=43 because that's the last 10th distinct FK!

Can anyone help me with writing SQL for this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry I forgot to add a tag for sql-server it is version 12.

Comment: @GurV I have tried to and partially manage to create temp table with only distinct rows and then "again" search the original table for all the rows with those FK's, but that was bad solution since I know that there must be a way to write that properly and not to "hammer" db with multiple selects and temp tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this in standard SQL is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.fk in (select t2.fk
               from t t2
               group by t2.fk
               order by t2.fk
               fetch first 10 rows only
              );
```

The exact syntax might vary by database, particularly for the `fetch first` clause.

Comment: Thx Gordon this actually did it, of course I had to change a bit of store procedure to "get" the "t" table but actually works like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 FK,Name,UserName,Asignee,Comment      
from
(

select
 FK,Name,UserName,Asignee,Comment      
 ,dense_rank() over (order by FK) dr
 from table
 ) a
 where dr<=10
```